# How to run exception Unit test for one function that calls another function inside of it

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock

I am trying to do exception unit test for `check_name()` function but `create_list()` is also called. Is there any way I can mock the output of `create_list()` instead of executing it?

```
def create_list(token):
   return service_list


def check_name(token, name):

   response = create_list(token)
   existed_list = [app.name for app in response.details]

   if name in existed_list:
      raise NameExists()
```

I tried this but it still called `create_list()`

```
def test_exception_existed_name(self):
    existed_list = [ "p", "r", "g", "x"]
    with pytest.raises(NameExists):
        check_name(token,  "g")
```

`check_name()` and `create_list()` in `sp.py`

```
project 
│
└───src
│   └───sp_api
│           └───api
│               sp.py
│   
└───tests
       test_sp.py
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mock `create_list`; you just created a variable named `existed_list` in a scope that `check_name` wouldn't look in even if `existed_list` weren't defined. You need to use something like `unittest.mock.patch`

```
def test_exception_existed_name(self):
    with pytest.raises(NameExists):
        with unittest.mock.patch('create_list', return_value=["p", "r", "g", "x"]):
             check_name(token, "g")
```

(Depending on where your test is actually defined, you may need to adjust the name you are patching; see https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch)

(I believe `pytest` itself also provides facilities for patching things without using `unittest.mock.patch` directly, but I am not familiar with them.)

Comment: I want to clarify that the output of `create_list()` is a json response and `existed_list` is obtained from a json file. Is there any way I can get the list after mocking the `create_list` ?

Comment: Fixed the call to `patch` to make `create_list` something that *returns* a specific value when called, rather than making `create_list` the returned value itself. That was just a dumb mistake on my part.

Comment: I still got the error `TypeError: Need a valid target to patch. You supplied: 'create_list'`

Comment: That's why I referred you to the "where to patch" page. There is not enough information in your question to determine the correct name to patch.

Comment: I changed to `with unittest.mock.patch('sp.create_list', return_value=["p", "r", "g", "x"])` but it `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sp'`